# Exclude a category from the_content() wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Thanks in advance for looking and offering any help you can, I have limited knowledge with this.

I am trying to exclude a category from the WordPress loop so whatever is posted to that category is not posted on the blog page. I have tried adding a function below

```
function remove_home_category( $query ) {
 if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-4' );
   }
 }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_home_category' );
```

I did not build the blog page but it looks to be pretty custom, any help is so greatly appreciated. here is the what I have in the template.

```
<div>
<?php
        get_template_part( 'parts/blog', 'header' );
        get_template_part( 'parts/blog', 'featured' );
        get_template_part( 'parts/blog', 'editor-picks' );

?>
</div>
<div class="container wpc-container" style=" <?php echo ( !empty($hgr_page_top_padding) ? ' padding-top:'.esc_attr($hgr_page_top_padding).'px!important;' : '' ); echo ( !empty($hgr_page_btm_padding) ? ' padding-bottom:'.esc_attr($hgr_page_btm_padding).'px!important;' : '' );?> ">
  <div class="slideContent gu12">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php if(is_paged()) : ?>
  <?php paginate_comments_links(); ?>
  <?php endif;?>
  <?php comments_template(); ?>
  <?php if(is_paged()) : ?>
  <?php paginate_comments_links(); ?>
  <?php endif;?>

  </div>
</div>
```

when I remove the container div, all of the blog posts disappear, so I assume my category exclusion should go somewhere in there? But I don't know where or what.

Comment: You added your hook in the theme's functions.php file?

Comment: hey, yea i added in the functions.php but whenever i publish the post it shows up in the main feed.

Comment: i should also note, its using a theme called navy, and the blog page is not the homepage.

Comment: Ok, if its not the home page, you can try removing the is_home() condition

Comment: that does not work either.

Comment: To try to debug this, I guess just remove the two conditions all together and make sure the category id is correct? I'd try to do a manual WP_Query on some other page with the cat exclusion and see if that works at least.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, my suspicion would be the `$query->is_main_query()` condition in your hooked function. This function will only return `true` if the code is running in [the main WordPress "loop"](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), and the standard code for the main loop isn't present in that template.

You could fix either by removing that condition from your hooked function, or rewriting the template to use the standard loop when outputting the page content (which would probably be the better approach long-term, since there are lots of other things inside WP that will only work consistently inside the loop anyway).

Comment: thank you for your response! that did not work either, the post still shows on the blog page in the main feed.

Comment: Make sure your hooked code is actually running on that page -- remove all the contents of the hooked function and replace them with a [wp_die](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) message, e.g.

`wp_die('Is this function actually getting run?');`

Then reload the blog page. If the page dies halfway through loading with the message you passed to wp_die(), you know at least that you hooked into the right place. If it doesn't die, then the problem is that you've hooked into the wrong hook.

Comment: looks like im hooked into the right place, soon as a reload the message loads instead of the blog content.